# While opening the Firefox driver in webdriver am getting below error

Tags: java, selenium

While running below code i am getting error,
can some one pls help?
what is the issue
My Code :

```
WebDriver wd=new FirefoxDriver();
wd.get("https://google.co.in");
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'INL-281384-1', ip: '10.14.225.69', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about this problem: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3000

#56, #57 are helpful comments... "you may try increasing the default maximum number of ephemeral TCP ports as written here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196271/en-us"